# Why doesn't Ubuntu install recognize there's an existing Ubuntu OS installed?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lvm

Before reading further: my situation is DIFFERENT from another question here with similar title; others will likely have my problem scenario so seeking an answer relevant to this scenario.

(1) I have previously installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop on "bare metal" HDD (no previous Windows or other OS; BTW, this is one of the factors that makes this situation very different from other questions/problems posted here).  Therefore, the boot loader installed and it's location, along with partitions etc, is what Ubuntu does "stock" from the LiveDVD.

(2) During installation of the existing Ubuntu 16.04, I installed it with Logical Volume Manager (LVM) (something I'll not likely do again in the future, given the fits & problems I'm now having trying to solve this problem).

(3) Now it's months later and I'm trying to install an application program that will not run on Ubuntu 16.04, it requires Ubuntu 14.04 instead.  SO, I'm trying to create a dual-boot configuration with 14.04 installed "alongside" 16.04.

(4) When attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop from liveDVD, the installer does not detect my existing 16.04 OS.  It wants me to select a volume with no prompt as to which one I should select, and I am very suspicious it will wipe my existing 16.04 installation, apps (one of which took a week to get configured to work) and data, thus I don't want to risk blindly selecting a volume.

==> WHY doesn't 14.04 installer see my existing 16.04 OS?  Is there anything I can do to force the installer to see it?

(5) I sensed my problem may be related to LVM, so I looked at my existing disk partitioning and LVM config.  I saw that the LVM Volume Group (ubuntu-vg) "Physical Partition" (not to be confused with the REAL disk partition) was taking up the entire HDD space/sectors, so I successfully reduced it (/dev/sda5, which is partition type 8e "Linux LVM") to about half of the real HDD space, along with the associated Logical Volumes (vg-root & vg-swap_1), moved the LVM swap partition (vg-swap_1, which mounts as /dev/sda1 partition type 83 "Linux") from the end of the real disk to the beginning of the volume group space, leaving the rest of the real disk space as "unallocated" space with no file system.  BTW, I found the information in the answers to question post here "How can I resize a LVM partition? (ie: physical volume)" along with other info elsewhere very helpful in completing that process safely, a lot of stuff involved in doing it that likely is irrelevant to my remaining problem so won't recount that here.

(6) One odd thing that bugs me now is that, despite reducing the LVM Physical Volume /dev/sda5 down to half the real HDD space (all on the first half of the drive), the "real" disk partition /dev/sda2 (partition type 5 "Extended"), that the LVM physical volume /dev/sda5 is a member of, is still taking up the entire drive.  That is preventing me from manually creating another Primary real disk partition ala /dev/sda3, as there is no more space available for that.

==> I think the Ubuntu 14.04 installer needs a new Primary partition to install into and not step on the existing 16.04 ??  AM I right?  If yes, and IF I can get the 14.04 installer to see my existing 16.04 will it reduce the size of the sda2 partition in order to create another Primary partition for itself?  If not, then perhaps I need to find a way to do it manually before the 14.04 installer sees it.

==> Should I find a way to reduce the amount of real drive space that /dev/sda2 extended partition is using, before installing 14.04, and if yes, how can I do that?  Plus possibly manually creating a new real HDD Primary partition sda3?

(7) Another odd thing that bugs me is the statement in fdisk (see additional info below) that a couple of the LVM volumes "doesn't contain a valid partition table".  I'm thinking that this may be reporting because the olde fdisk utility doesn't understand LVM; I'm thinking that because my existing 16.04 LVM OS installation is running just fine, no problems.

==> Should I be concerned about this, is a clue to my problem, or am I right that fdisk doesn't understand LVM partitions?

Here's some additional info to help someone answer me...

---

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5   VG ubuntu-vg   lvm2 [148.60 GiB / 5.95 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [148.60 GiB] / in use: 1 [148.60 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa3e613f1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      999423      498688   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1001470   625141759   312070145    5  Extended
/dev/sda5         1001472   312641535   155820032   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 148.9 GB, 148872626176 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18099 cylinders, total 290766848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               148.60 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              38041
  Free PE               1523
  Allocated PE          36518
  PV UUID               iHqE9w-03C8-MdzR-BipQ-S88d-7Xr1-W1rSUB


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                mBymjr-0ITB-HZ18-d8wj-IwcC-MAaV-NoIZcd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2016-07-06 01:24:50 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                138.65 GiB
  Current LE             35494
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                p5Al8f-4m08-yhoA-Q3bX-MsJw-6v1P-i2ba4K
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2016-09-21 23:21:00 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Gparted screen-shot of current config:
[image: Gparted screen-shot of current config]

Comment: You actually should install inside the LVM using Something Else and mounting LVM and to create additional logical partition(s). Or backup & reinstall both  systems using standard MBR or gpt partitions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM